# Integrating Git and Github with AWS Lambda while Keeping the Built-In Code Editor - Deployment Help Needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda, github-actions, serverless

I'm currently working on a project integrating Git and GitHub with AWS Lambda, and I've run into a few challenges that I hope the community can assist me with.

Firstly, we want to retain the use of the built-in code editor that AWS Lambda offers, as well as our existing Lambda layers. We're not utilizing SAM CLI because, frankly, the deployment time is excessively slow for our needs. Instead, we've been relying on the in-built code editor, which has been working well for us so far.

Now, what I really need help with is the following:

Deployment to GitHub: I want to understand the process to deploy our code to GitHub first and then to Lambda. We need a seamless integration, and I'm unsure about the best practices or tools for this specific use case.

Relationship between Lambda and GitHub Repo: We need to create a one-to-one relationship between a Lambda function and a GitHub repository. This means every commit in the repo triggers the Lambda function and vice versa.

Custom Commit Messages: The ability to generate our own commit messages programmatically is really nice to have for us. Any advice on how this can be achieved would be immensely helpful.

We're trying to build a robust, automated workflow that keeps everything in sync without sacrificing the tools and features we've grown to depend on. If anyone has experience with this sort of integration or has any recommendations on the best way to proceed, I'd be very grateful for your insights.

Thank you for taking the time to read this post, and I look forward to hearing from the experts in this community!

We are mainly on the planning stage and trying to figure out the best solution to this, any potential solutions, hints and tips would be helpful